# Azure Portal- The service is unavailable Error 503

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Microsoft Azure. I've created a service which is running in the Azure Portal. [See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8mxc.png). I have created a pipeline in Azure and created a release but I keep getting service unavailable see the error below.

```
> 2020-12-29T12:02:14.3749416Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2020-12-29T12:02:14.3769585Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Site Unavailable (CODE: 503
```

On the Azure Portal when I click on the URL of my service I also get a service unavailable message. I know it's a free trial I'm running but I checked the status and the credits are still available to use.